# Conditionally autoFocus the first input

Tags: reactjs

I'm generating input fields by mapping over an array but I want just the first input to be auto-focused...

```
      {keys.map((item, index) => {
        return (
          <div className='poster--keys-values' key={index + 20}>
            <div className='poster--key-title' key={index + 10}>{item}</div>
            <input
              {index === 1 ? 'autoFocus' : null} // <===== This isnt right
              type='text'
              id={item}
              name={item}
              key={index}
              className='poster--value-title'
              onChange={onChange}
            />
          </div>
        );
      })}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is `autoFocus` attribute, so you can do this:

```
...
<input
  autoFocus={index === 0}
  ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
{index === 1 ? 'autoFocus' : null}
```

write:

```
autoFocus={index === 1}
```

Should work as expected :)